# pandas resample yearly with custom start date

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample stock prices yearly but with a custom start date (not natural/calendar year). This is to simulate fiscal year which may be different from calendar year.

I have:

```
Date
2010-02-01     39.921856
2010-02-02     39.929314
2010-02-03     40.511570
2010-02-04     39.541145
2010-02-05     39.899464
                 ...    
2022-01-24    138.550598
2022-01-25    135.536484
2022-01-26    134.152969
2022-01-27    134.241882
2022-01-28    135.902145
Name: Adj Close, Length: 3021, dtype: float64
```

I want to calculate the cumulative return every fiscal year, so I need the closing price for the last day of each fiscal year. For example, this day is 1 Feb, so I want to get:

```
2010-02-01     39.921856
2011-02-01     xxx
2012-02-01     xxx
2013-02-01     xxx
```

I tried resample('1Y'), date_range etc. but pandas force calendar year no matter what. I keep getting either 01-01 or 12-31 depending on if I ask for year start or end. The origin argument for resample also does nothing:

```
df = df.resample('Y', origin='2010-02-01').last()
```

How do I get what I want?

Comment: What about you create a third column df['fiscal_fake_date'] = df['date'] - pd.to_timedelta(31,  unit='day') and then consider the years based on this column?
It's not the cleanest solution, but it should do the trick.

Comment: @Costas yes i know this trick, but I thought the pd.resample origin argument should work for my case, I don't know what am I doing wrong here. According to the website docs it should work.

Comment: becuz 'Y' means calendar year end. you can use `origin` with '10D' or '5T' and so on. you cant use with start or end timestamp like 'Y', 'M' and so on.